# Is an orthonormal basis for an inner product vector space always required?

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems that an orthonormal basis is always used to define a vector in a vector space and perform function analyses. I understand that in such a basis, it’s easier to define the coordinates of a vector. Is an orthonormal basis always required to define vectors in vector spaces? If not, how are vectors defined? Take for example the case of a two-dimensional Euclidean inner-product vector space [cosine(ax), sine(ax)] basis used in this link: [Finding orthonormal basis from orthogonal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839456/finding-orthonormal-basis-from-orthogonal-basis)

Comment: How do you define *point*?

Comment: No. You can use any basis you like, just like in "regular" linear algebra. However, orthonormal bases are REALLY nice, so we use them because they typically allow us to say more than we might otherwise be able to

Comment: Asking you *required for what?* will help you to understand when orthonormal basis are useful.

Comment: By " point", I mean a vector in the vector space. A point or a vector is defined by its coordinates. A basis is required to define vectors by their coordinates.

Comment: A point is not defined by its coordinates! The function $\cos(ax)$ is a point in the space of continuous real functions. We don't have to specify coordinates to talk about the point.

Comment: Thanks. I meant to say coordinates of the end point of a vector.